# Linear Algebra Done Right solution problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Could you please explain me more step by step the solution to problem 5 in the [link](http://linearalgebras.com/2015/02/exercises-of-chapter-3-c-part-1.html)? I cannot understand the logic flow behind it. For example, why for $(a1, a2,\dots, a_m)$ there is $a_i \ne 0$ and not $a_1 = 1$ as stated in the problem?

Thank you for help.

Comment: A quick statement that may help: if you have a linear operator $T : V \to W$ and have bases for $V$ and $W$, then $T_{ij}$ is the coefficient of $w_i$ in the expansion of $Tv_j$ in the basis for $W$.

Comment: The body of your Question should be as self-contained as possible.  Please restate the problem 5 and the outlined solution in your own words, as this will help the Reader understand what assistance you want.

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that $a_1$ can be made to either one or zero be picking the right base, besides other stuff.
If all $a_i=0$, you are done.
If there is one $a_i\neq 0$, you can use the base transformation shown in the proof to create a new base with $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...) = (1,0,0,...)$.